# Different methods for determining whether a number is included in a given list

Tags: lua, comparison, lua-table

Is it faster to check whether a number is equivalent to another, or to look up the number in a table?

I have a program where commands sent from a server are received as numbers. Commands are sent frequently: anywhere from 1/second to 30+/second. Certain commands are ignored while others trigger various events. Would it be better to determine which event to trigger by doing this:

```
function incoming_integer(n)
  if n == 33 then
    print('a')
  elseif n == 44 then
    print('b')
  elseif n == 567 then
    print('c')
    ... (the actual list is occasionally pretty long: upwards of ten valid numbers)
  end
end
```

or this:

```
functions = {
  [33] = function() print('a') end,
  [44] = function() print('b') end,
  [567] = function() print('c') end,
  ...
}
relevant_commands = {[33]= true, [44]=true, [567]=true ...}
function incoming_integer(n)
  if relevant_commands[n] then
    functions[n]()
  end
end
```

Is there a point at which one method becomes more efficient?
What if the commands were instead sent as strings?

Comment: There is no need for `relevant_commands`. Just use `if functions[n]~=nil then functions[n]() end`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your throughput, I would suggest that the overhead for either mechanism is likely to be negligible.
I ran very quick and dirty test of the overhead of the table lookup for both string and numeric keys. See below. Even with a large number of keys and a high hit rate, I struggled to get >1us overhead even on the slowest box I could find.

```
f = {}
function incoming_integer(n)
    local t = f[n]
    return t and t()
end

SIZE = 10000
RAN = 20000
REPEAT = 10000000

for i =1,SIZE do
    --f[math.random(RAN)] = function() return "z" end
    f[tostring(math.random(RAN))] = function() return "z" end
end


tm = os.time()
for i = 1,REPEAT do
    --math.random(RAN)
    tostring(math.random(RAN))
end
print(os.difftime(os.time(),tm))

tm = os.time()
for i = 1,REPEAT do
    --incoming_integer(math.random(RAN))
    incoming_integer(tostring(math.random(RAN)))
end
print(os.difftime(os.time(),tm))
```

Comment: I tried to do something similar, but I guess os.time() only shows full seconds, so both methods always showed 0. Thanks for this. I guess it doesn't really matter!

Comment: @ms4000kb: Use [`os.clock()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-os.clock) instead of `os.time()` for something like this ...

Comment: @ms4000kb I ran a 10M loop so it registered something. You can get more accurate timers but, as you say, there's no need

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger different events with the returned numbers, I would use this way...

```
function trigger( value )
if ( value == "..." ) then
    triggerThis()
elseif ( value == "..." ) then
    triggerElse()
    -- and so on
    end
end

function incoming_integer(n)
if ( n ) then -- check if variable is incoming to prevent errors
    trigger( n )
else
    alert( "noop, there is nothing here" )
    end
end
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. That's roughly the first option. My worry with it is that if there are, say, 100 valid commands, it could require a bit of labor to go through and compare the incoming commands up to 100 times each. I have no idea how the inner mechanics of the == operator work, though, so it could be fairly trivial. Similarly, I don't really know how long it takes to look up a value in a table, so I imagine there must be a point at which the two roughly equal each other.

Comment: My guess is that with 100 commands the table-version is faster than the nested-if-version (and certainly nicer), but I'd have to write a small test program to confirm this (which probably you should have done in the first place) ...

Comment: Thanks. I did try to test it, but I wasn't able to see any difference between the two using os.time() since it only returned full second differences.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try keys. Didn't tested it just an example.
http://lua-users.org/wiki/TablesTutorial

```
table = { [33]="a", [44]="b", [567]="c" }

function onCall( value ) -- if 33
    if ( table[value] ) then
        return( table[value] ) -- then if exists return a
    end
end

onCall( 33 ) -- now it will search in table and get key
```

EDIT: You could name the triggered functions like the number, so you can directly trigger them. This would save a lot of time!

Comment: No need for the `if`, just return the table value.

Comment: @Maurize: In case of an unknown key the function wouldn't return an error but `nil`, which it does now as well.

Comment: yeah you're right, nevermind. My thoughts are wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

```
functions = {[33] = function() print('a') end, etc...}

setmetatable(functions, {__index = function() return function() end end}) -- return empty function if no defined function is found
```

Usage:

```
functions[32]() -- ignores
functions[33]() -- does defined function
```